# Place an imageView over another ImageView : Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a hierarchy of views such that :

```
BiggerView extends ViewGroup
      |
      |
      |----------------------MyImageView extends ImageView
```

The `BiggerView` is as big as the `MyImageView` and now I need to put 2 small images on `MyImageView` at the position where user presses `longPress`.These two small images  shall be moveable/dragable over the `MyImageView`. Now there are two parts to this problem :

1. How to put these two images over `MyImageView`. I know Absolute Layout used to be one solution for this but now it is highly unrecommended. Drawing these images as drawables may not give me gesture control events on these 2 images.I believe this should not be a new problem and many other must have faced such a need and would have accomplished it.
2. After having placed these 2 images on `MyImageView`. What approach should I follow to move these images on `onMove` event ? Should I just call layout method with new dX and dY ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a relative layout you can layer images just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using framelayout you can place one image over the other, then you can set visibility in java depending on the image you want to set as visible.

Answer (score 0):

a. You can use `RelativeLayout` and position the new `ImageView`s relative to the container such that they overlap `MyImageView`

b. You can use `Animation` to move images around. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html